# How to remove unused space from SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a SQL Server table that had lots of data in a `nvarchar(max)` column. I set that columns value to all nulls so now the table should not take up much space. How can I reclaim that space?

I've tried `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` and I've also tried backing up and restoring the database but the space seems not to be recovered.  If I drop the table and recreate it with an insert/select type thing the space is recovered.

thanks

Comment: **One word:** DON'T - SQL Server will **reuse** that space for future allocations. Shrinking database tables and fiddly stuff like that was great in the dBase days - don't do it anymore - it's pointless, useless, actually contraproductive in many cases, and it wastes CPU cycles and can harm your database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [DBCC CLEANTABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx), "Reclaims space from dropped variable-length columns in tables or indexed views."

Comment: I tried DBCC CLEANTABLE and it finished very quickly saying success but did not change the space allocated to the table.  At the moment, the space taken is about 2GB and the data is only about 50MB.  Since this entire database is only about 150MB, it is impractical to just wait for another 2 GB of data to be added to it (and just let it be)

Comment: How are you determining space used? What does exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'  show? Is all the space in unused?

Comment: you can see from these 3 screen shots in a row that after running the cleantable, the space is the same used.  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cait44trz2ud4wo/su.png

Comment: tried the updateusage parameter on sp_spaceused? or are you also seeing the space consumed in the mdf in file system?

Comment: sorry for not know, but what is the syntax?  exec sp_spaceused 'EmailDetails' 'True'

Comment: exec sp_spaceused 'emaildetails',true

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [DBCC CLEANTABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx) and should be used like

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE (DB_NAME,"TABLE_NAME", 0)
WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
GO
```

A Quote of warning from MSDN document

> Best Practices
>
> DBCC CLEANTABLE should not be executed as a routine maintenance task.
>   Instead, use DBCC CLEANTABLE after you make significant changes to
>   variable-length columns in a table or indexed view and you need to
>   immediately reclaim the unused space. Alternatively, you can rebuild
>   the indexes on the table or view; however, doing so is a more
>   resource-intensive operation.

As Mark has already mentioned, you should refrain from doing so. It's not needed cause next time you insert data to those `nvarchar(max)` column it will use the space again. So, essentially you will not get any benefit out of it.

Take a look at this post for reasoning behind the same

[reclaim-the-unused-space-from-sql-server-2005-database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/44c9496f-aa28-437c-a1cb-1879d4dd8899/reclaim-the-unused-space-from-sql-server-2005-database?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem, when needed to cleanup a number of DEV databases.

The best way that worked for me was first dropping the column, then running the clean table and then shrink database. And in the end re-create the column.

```
Alter table MyTable drop column MyColumn
DBCC CLEANTABLE(MyDB, MyTable, 0)
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ('MyDB')
ALter table MyTable ADD MyColumn nvarchar(max) NULL
```

According to documentation:
[CLEANTABLE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) reclaims space after a variable-length column is dropped.
[SHRINKDATABASE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488(v=sql.110).aspx) operation is most effective after an operation that creates lots of unused space, such as a truncate table or a drop table operation.

Answer (score 0):

`DBCC CLEANTABLE` is a good solution but sometimes it's not possible to use DBCC commands due to permission. Another solution (thas also require some permissions) is to recompress the table partition(s).

This command reduced drastically the unused space:

```
alter table [shema_name].[table_name] rebuild partition = all with (data_compression = page)
```

It also reduce the disk space with data_compression.

If you do not want compression you can also use:

```
alter table [shema_name].[table_name] rebuild partition = all with (data_compression = none)
```